# Why doesn't this second nohup command run?

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal, scripts, sh

Everything runs except the last line:

```
#!/bin/bash
xinput set-prop 11 "Device Accel Profile" -1
xinput set-prop 11 "Device Accel Velocity Scaling" 1
xinput set-prop 11 "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 2
nohup java -jar /home/owner/Desktop/Dropbox/TimerApp.jar > /dev/null 2>&1 &
sleep 5
nohup abiword "/home/owner/Desktop/Dropbox/TODO.rtf" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

I start the script called "startup.sh" by double clicking it in Nautilus. Both "run in terminal" and "run" produce the same result.

Comment: Remove the redirection (at least the redirection of stderr) in the second command to see what error is shown.

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
sleep 1
```

to the end of the script seems to have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems `nohup` doesn't ignore SIGHUP (or maybe other signals) until it is fully started.

A better alternative for `nohup` would be:

```
your_command & disown
```

In your case:

```
abiword "/home/owner/Desktop/Dropbox/TODO.rtf" > /dev/null 2>&1 & disown
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't have Abiword installed?

Open a terminal and run this:

```
abiword "/home/owner/Desktop/Dropbox/TODO.rtf"
```

Without the error suppression you should be able to see what the problem is and work towards fixing it.

Comment: Running that command works fine. I do have AbiWord installed. This is why I'm stumped.

Comment: What happens if you strip it back in the script? Just the second one.